# Two different loops for calculation and drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So i have been looking into ways to improve motion smoothness and performance on my canvas animations.

And a quick google on some game development forum suggests using two different loops one for calculating and one for drawing... the example code was shown like this:

```
function mainLoop() {
  // all of your logic goes here, moving positions, checking inputs, etc...
  // I guess it's proper to put all drawing to "off screen" canvases here too.
  ...
  setTimeout(mainLoop, 1000 / desiredFPS);
}

function drawingLoop() {
  //only drawing commands to the visible canvas goes here
  ...
  requestAnimationFrame(drawingLoop);
}

//when your assets are loaded you just simply make a 
//call to each loop to get them started...
mainLoop();
drawingLoop();
```

Is this actually the best way to do it ?

I currently have all my logic and draw in the same loop. I presumed two different loops would actually slow the frame rate down aswell as the smoothness of it all ?

My current approach is more like this:

```
function loop() {
  calculate(); // calculate everything
  draw();      // draw everything
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}    
loop();
```

Why is it suggested to do two different loops are there any pros and cons doing it that way?

Comment: `setTimeout` will just push at top of the stack of things to do when given time has elapsed, so I don't see **any** pros of doing it with an rAF loop running. If you need some timing in the logics, use the rAF timestamp.

Comment: So you agree i should separate the calculations out of RAF? @Kaiido

Comment: No, the inverse, but I may be wrong, wait for some real answers. Also, you could try to make the call to `requestAnimationFrame()` at top of your loop, I have the belief that it makes it more stable, but I don't know for sure either :-/

Comment: BTW, source of where i read about the use of two loops: http://www.chandlerprall.com/2012/06/requestanimationframe-is-not-your-logics-friend/  perhaps it makes sense to some one who understands it more than i !

Comment: to me the only thing that makes sense in all of it is [this comment](http://www.chandlerprall.com/2012/06/requestanimationframe-is-not-your-logics-friend/#comment-1136) . Also, even in his example he is doing something *stupid* : call the logics before the drawing or you'll draw one frame late !

Comment: Personally for me I don't see any pros or cons, to me it just looks cleaner. You know where your logic code is and your draw code.

Comment: @Canvas, if in your rAF loop, let's call it `loop()`, you have one `update()`, which does the logics and one `draw()` which does the drawings. How is `var loop="function(){update(); draw(); requestAniamationFrame(loop)}` less clean than two separate loops `var draw = function(){ ... do_some_drawings(); requestAnimationFrame(draw);} var update = function(){update_some_stuff(); setTimeout(update, someOtherTimeIdontReallyHaveControlOnto);}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to improve performance and decouple calculations from the actual rendering, you should have a look at WebWorkers on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or [HTML5 rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/). They are basically sorts of threads, which let you offload some work from the main thread.

But when it comes to perf, you should probably have a look at the perf tools in Chrome, which might help you debunk other non-trivial parts of your code. Have a look at the [doc for the CPU profiling](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling)

Comment: Wait, what does it mean to decouple calculations ?

Comment: That was not very explicit :) The idea I wanted to express is dividing the code into two parts, one that does the rendering and another one that does the actual calculations.